# php: Keep only max values in an array?

Tags: php, arrays

Given a simple array like

```
$testarr = array("Donna"=>3, "Luke" => 4, "Pete" =>4, "Lola" => 1);
```

How can I keep only the max values?
I am aware I could do a

```
max($testarr);
```

and then loop through the array removing values that differ, but maybe sg like array_filter, or a more elegant one liner solution is available.

Comment: so you want to set every key in your array to be the one max value?

Comment: Nope, just remove keys / values that are lower than the max value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your one-liner using [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/kr/function.array-filter.php):

```
<?php

$testarr = array("Donna"=>3, "Luke" => 4, "Pete" =>4, "Lola" => 1);
$max = max($testarr);
$only_max = array_filter($testarr, function($item) use($max){ return $item == $max; });
var_dump( $only_max );
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  ["Luke"]=>
  int(4)
  ["Pete"]=>
  int(4)
}
```

Note that the [closure](http://php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php) function is referencing `$max`. As suggested by [@devon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1583522/devon), referencing the original array would make the code shorter & general, in exchange for calculation efficiency.

```
$only_max = array_filter($testarr, 
    function($item) use($testarr){ 
        return $item == max($testarr);
    });
```

Comment: Could make it shorter with `$only_max = array_filter($testarr, function($item) use($testarr){ return $item == max($testarr); });` but depending on opcache, your way would be more efficient :) but anyways, good use of a anonymous function.

Answer (score 2):

This will get you where you need to go:

```
<?php
function less_than_max($element)
{
    // returns whether the input element is less than max
    return($element < 10);
}


$array1 = array("a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3, "d"=>4, "e"=>5);
$array2 = array("a" => 6, "b"=>7, "c"=>8, "d"=>9, "e"=>10, "f"=>11, "g"=>12);
$max = 3;

echo "Max:\n";
print_r(array_filter($array1, "less_than_max"));
echo "Max:\n";
print_r(array_filter($array2, "less_than_max"));
?>
```